# INSERT all the ids of a table together with the last inserted id of another using "NEW.idtable"

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: The first is called "paciente" it has an ID as the primary key which is called idpaciente The second is called "sessao", in it I want to add the current date every day and also has an id called idsessao And I have the third one called sessao_has_paciente which is the N: M relationship table between these two tables. The question I have is this: I insert the current date in the sessao table according to an event that runs every 1 day, and I put a trigger that after inserting in that table would list the idsessao of the second table with all the idpaciente of the first in the third table called `sessao_has_paciente.

My trigger code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO sessao_has_paciente SELECT idpaciente from paciente, NEW.idsessao
```

The error that MySQL returns is that there is no NEW.idsessao field, without this NEW.idsessao field the INSERT works normally but I need to have this to insert the last session table ID for all rows of the paciente table.

CREATE TABLE 1

```
CREATE TABLE paciente (
  idpaciente int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dia_iddia int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  turno_idturno int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  medico_idmedico int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  tiposanguineo_idtiposanguineo int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  duracaohd_idduracaohd int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  frequenciahd_idfrequenciahd int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  cidade_idcidade int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  estado_idestado int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  profissao_idprofissao int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  tiposlogradouro_idtiposlogradouro int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  nome varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  apelido varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  bairro varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  cep varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  cpf varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  datanascimento date DEFAULT NULL,
  datainiciohd date DEFAULT NULL,
  endereco varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  numero varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  foto varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  pesoseco float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idpaciente),
  KEY fk_paciente_tiposanguineo1_idx (tiposanguineo_idtiposanguineo),
  KEY fk_paciente_duracaohd1_idx (duracaohd_idduracaohd),
  KEY fk_paciente_frequenciahd1_idx (frequenciahd_idfrequenciahd),
  KEY fk_paciente_cidade1_idx (cidade_idcidade),
  KEY fk_paciente_profissao1_idx (profissao_idprofissao),
  KEY fk_paciente_tiposlogradouro1_idx (tiposlogradouro_idtiposlogradouro),
  KEY fk_paciente_turno1_idx (turno_idturno),
  KEY fk_paciente_medico1_idx (medico_idmedico),
  KEY fk_paciente_dia1_idx (dia_iddia),
  KEY fk_paciente_estado1_idx (estado_idestado),
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_cidade1 FOREIGN KEY (cidade_idcidade) REFERENCES cidade (idcidade) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_dia1 FOREIGN KEY (dia_iddia) REFERENCES dia (iddia) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_duracaohd1 FOREIGN KEY (duracaohd_idduracaohd) REFERENCES duracaohd (idduracaohd) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_estado1 FOREIGN KEY (estado_idestado) REFERENCES estado (idestado) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_frequenciahd1 FOREIGN KEY (frequenciahd_idfrequenciahd) REFERENCES frequenciahd (idfrequenciahd) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_medico1 FOREIGN KEY (medico_idmedico) REFERENCES medico (idmedico) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_profissao1 FOREIGN KEY (profissao_idprofissao) REFERENCES profissao (idprofissao) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_tiposanguineo1 FOREIGN KEY (tiposanguineo_idtiposanguineo) REFERENCES tiposanguineo (idtiposanguineo) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_tiposlogradouro1 FOREIGN KEY (tiposlogradouro_idtiposlogradouro) REFERENCES tiposlogradouro (idtiposlogradouro) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paciente_turno1 FOREIGN KEY (turno_idturno) REFERENCES turno(idturno) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

TRIGGER TABLE 1:

```
  CREATE DEFINER=ConexaoClinica@% TRIGGER testemodeldb2.paciente_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON paciente FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO fichasala (idfichasala, paciente_idpaciente) VALUES (DEFAULT, NEW.idpaciente);

END
```

This Trigger is working normally as it should.

TABLE 2 CREATE

```
 CREATE TABLE sessao (
      idsessao int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      diasessao date DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (idsessao)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

TRIGGER TABLE 2 :

```
CREATE DEFINER=ConexaoClinica@% TRIGGER testemodeldb2.sessao_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON sessao FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sessao_has_paciente (paciente_idpaciente, sessao_idsessao) SELECT idpaciente from paciente, new.idsessao;
END
```

TABLE 3 CREATE :

```
CREATE TABLE sessao_has_paciente (
  idsessao_has_paciente int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sessao_idsessao int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  paciente_idpaciente int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idsessao_has_paciente),
  KEY fk_sessao_has_paciente_paciente1_idx (paciente_idpaciente),
  KEY fk_sessao_has_paciente_sessao1_idx (sessao_idsessao),
  CONSTRAINT fk_sessao_has_paciente_paciente1 FOREIGN KEY (paciente_idpaciente) REFERENCES paciente (idpaciente) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_sessao_has_paciente_sessao1 FOREIGN KEY (sessao_idsessao) REFERENCES sessao (idsessao) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is my problem, this `"NEW.idsessao"` Only works correctly when I perform this trigger on table 2 `SESSAO`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=ConexaoClinica@% TRIGGER testemodeldb2.sessao_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON sessao FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sessao_has_paciente (paciente_idpaciente, sessao_idsessao) VALUES ('1', new.idsessao);
END
```

In other words, I have to enter the ID manually, I didn't want this I wanted all IDS in table 1 to be inserted with only the last ID inserted in table 2 in the third table, and I found the way to do this through a subquery and here's the trigger I tried:

```
CREATE DEFINER=ConexaoClinica@% TRIGGER testemodeldb2.sessao_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON sessao FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sessao_has_paciente (paciente_idpaciente, sessao_idsessao) SELECT idpaciente from paciente, new.idsessao;
END
```

But mysql returns the error saying that the field new.idsessao does not exist...

If I do this same trigger mentioned above without NEW.idsessao it works normally, that is, each one of them works in a different way but I wanted them to work together to be able to make this insert.

[MODEL OF DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlVqY.png)

I'll explain everything I want to do from the beginning so that you can understand well.

I want to do a session automation.

How I thought about doing this:
Create an event that every 1 day if the day is between MONDAY TO SATURDAY, an insert will be made with the current date in the `diasessao` field.

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT added
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2021-02-21 00:10:00'
OF
  IF DAYOFWEEK (curdate ()) IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) THEN
   INSERT INTO session VALUES (DEFAULT, CURDATE ());
  END IF;
  delimiter;
```

When something is inserted in the `SESSION` table it will trigger a trigger that takes ALL the IDS from the `PATIENT` table and correlates with the LAST ID INSERTED in that `SESSION` table and all this goes to table 3 `PATIENTE_HAS_SESSAO`, that is, for each id in the `PATIENT` table a line will be made with the patient ID + the last ID inserted in the `SESSION` table

But patients are also separated by DAYS OF THE WEEK, there are patients who have sessions on MONDAY, WEDNESDAY and FRIDAY and others TUESDAY, THURSDAY AND SATURDAY, this is fixed, it does not vary so I would have to do a WHERE with the IF in this trigger just as I did with the event the whole problem is that I am not able to get the LAST INSERT as I did on the trigger of `PATIENT` =`INSERT INTO fichasala (idfichasala, patient_idpaciente) VALUES (DEFAULT, NEW.idpaciente);`
In this case, when I use a SUBQUERY, MySQL says that the NEW.idsessao field does not exist.

Comment: please add the tables and your trigger, so that we can understand what you try to achieve

Comment: Okay, I improved it, if possible see if you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK that is much better.

The Trigger must be different, because your solution produced a syntax error

```
CREATE DEFINER=ConexaoClinica@% TRIGGER testemodeldb2.sessao_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON sessao FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sessao_has_paciente (paciente_idpaciente, sessao_idsessao) SELECT idpaciente, new.idsessao from paciente;
END
```

delimiter |

For your  event only enter the curdate without the autoincrment field

```
CREATE EVENT added
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2021-02-21 00:10:00'
DO
  IF DAYOFWEEK (curdate ()) IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) THEN
   INSERT INTO session (`diasessao`) VALUES ( CURDATE());
  END IF;
  delimiter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this NEW.tablename in mysql. What you can do is retrieve the last inserted ID from a specific table like this:

```
SELECT id FROM sessao ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```